# how to use web hooks on Buildbot (gitlab integration)

Tags: gitlab, buildbot

I am quite curious to know how do you actually use the buildbot when you have a repo on gitlab.

From what I understand, there is no way to upload the py files, which are triggered by the post-commit hook, so I am not exactly clear how do you tell gitlab to send the changes in the codebase to the buildbot, and how the buildbot knows about these changes sent.

We are planning to switch soon to gitlab, and I am looking ahead to avoid to get stuck when the real fun will begin.

Does anyone have any pointer about the integration and communication between Gitlab and Buildbot?

The info on the official documentation of Buildbot is not really clear; I have read about web hooks but I am not really getting how they work.

Comment: From the total lack of reply, I assume that nobody uses gitlab at all, with buildbot. This may be an issue, and probably I need to look into other products that support gitlab (and has hopefully a more widespread community...when it is time to ask questions about Buildbot, 9 out of 10 there is no answer ). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main issue is the incompatibility of the github module for Buildbot; once the Gitlab will make possible to have either Gitlab or Github hooks, it will work without problems.

http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3787958-web-hooks-data-posts-should-be-github-compatible

Hope that this will help people looking for info, so they avoid to bang their head on the wall in search of an answer :)

Comment: This is *not*  a problem solved, in fact, your link has a comment saying they WON'T implement that thing, so your answer is really misleading.

Comment: At that time there were no other solution. Specifying that there is no solution, is a legiit solution.

Answer (score 5):

## There is a Gitlab Hook

They've added a [Gitlab Hook](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-wwwhooks.html). You can use it the same way as the Github one.

> The GitLab hook is as simple as GitHub one and it also takes no
>   options.

```
c['www'] = dict(...,
    change_hook_dialects={ 'gitlab' : True }
)
```